# Verify if banner is shown

Tags: marketing, banners

I have contracts with different websites that should display animated gif banners for promotion of some of my products.

These banners should be shown in certain pages (URLs).

I would like to implement an automatic way to check if the banner is really shown. To verify that the contractual stuff is fulfilled by my partners. I should keep in mind that in some cases only 1 out of 3 visits shows my banner (partial timeslot).

Could this be done with a script?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to verify if it is on the screen (user has scrolled to it)?   Do you need to verify the contents of the gif (correct colors as opposed to replaced by a transparent gif)?    Is it enough to know that the gif is in the document object model (DOM)?

Comment: I need to know if the gif is in the document object model (DOM) I guess. But to be sure I should compare the image to a local copy I think